# How do I install libaio?

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install libaio with following command line :

```
sudo apt-get install libaio
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install automake libtool autoconf gcc-g++ gcc libaio libaio-dev make
```

but both of them doesn't work for me. How do I install libaio?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful description of a problem...

Comment: what do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Comment: I'm sorry maybe too hard you to understanding. I mean the command line can't install libaio

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to use [libaio1 package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libaio-dev), which provides the Linux kernel AIO access library - shared library

To install libaio Use the command

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

For more information of libaio look [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/libaio)

Comment: use `apt-cache policy libaio1` command to check

Comment: libaio1: Installed: 0.3.109-2ubuntu1 Candidate: 0.3.109-2ubuntu1 Version table: *** 0.3.109-2ubuntu1 0,
It's seems working. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have found it super useful to use `apt` instead of `apt-get` to search for packages that are available.

```
$ sudo apt search libaio

Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libaio-dev/trusty 0.3.109-4 amd64
  Linux kernel AIO access library - development files

libaio1/trusty 0.3.109-4 amd64
  Linux kernel AIO access library - shared library

libaio1-dbg/trusty 0.3.109-4 amd64
  Linux kernel AIO access library - debugging symbols
```

Then, once you have found the name of the correct package, you can install it. So in this case you can just run the command

```
sudo apt install -y libaio1
```

where again I have used `apt` instead of `apt-get`.

Comment: `apt` isn't a valid command on a Ubuntu system in the year 2011. `apt-search` works.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it is currently the year 2015.....

Comment: You are mistaken; it is currently the year 2023. ;)

Comment: Everybody wants to be Bob Hope...

Answer (score 0):

After many tries and errors, I used `sudo aptitude update` and `sudo aptitude upgrade` and it fixed all the dependencies for libaio1, libmecab2 and so on.