# Installation Error for MySQL Server on 16.10

Tags: server, apt, mysql

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 and was looking to install MySQL via sudo apt mysql-server mysql-client when I received the error "mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory." I discovered, however, that libaio1 had been installed via apt and the libaio.so.1 file existed in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu along with libaio.so.1.0.1, as well as /media/ubuntu/casper-rw/upper/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. I've purged the MySQL files and databases and retried with no success. How do I properly install MySQL? Thanks!

Comment: Trying to install MariaDB from mariadb-server also produced an error,  'trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml', which is also in package mysql-common 5.7.16-1ubuntu16.04.'

Comment: Now, after purging every trace of Mariadb and MySQL the Mariadb install is just saying 'subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127' and the MySQL install is producing the same error.

Comment: Same error installing percona-server:
'trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml', which is also in package mysql-common 5.7.16-1ubuntu16.04.'

Answer (score 0):

Try starting over utilizing a "`LAMP`" tutorial to guide you. The sources below pertain to Ubuntu 16.04. There may now be new posts for Ubuntu 16.10.

> LAMP Server is a collection of open source software used to create a
>   web server. The collection consists of:
>
> ```
> Linux – the operating system
> Apache server – the server
> MySQL – the database system
> PHP – the programming language
> ```

Quote above from: [SudoJuice](http://www.sudo-juice.com/install-lamp-server-ubuntu/)

[To install the default LAMP stack in Ubuntu 10.04 and above](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)
[Install Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.atlantic.net/community/howto/install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/)
[Install Lamp Server on Ubuntu](http://www.sudo-juice.com/install-lamp-server-ubuntu/)

Comment: Unfortunately, installing through the LAMP metapackage causes the exact same error, plus installing MySQL 5.6 through a deb package produces the same error as well. Where is this libaio.so.1 supposed to be located?

Comment: Going through the Ubuntu packages, the libaio.so.1 file has been installed in the correct location, which hasn't changed across  other distros. Making an i386 folder and moving the files in there doesn't help, chmoding with 755 and 777 doesn't help.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I'm on i386 on a live ubuntu system.  both libaio1 and libaio-dev are installed.

Comment: Try looking here: software installation - How do I install libaio? - Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/227791/how-do-i-install-libaio

Comment: Here is another possible problem/solution:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619298/libaio-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file

Comment: libaio1 is installed correctly and is the correct 64 bit version. When I do a fresh install of MySQL after deleting everything, I get the following:

Comment: Nov 03 14:02:41 ubuntu audit[8629]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbi
Nov 03 14:02:41 ubuntu audit[8629]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbi
Nov 03 14:02:41 ubuntu mysqld[8629]: /usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries:
Nov 03 14:02:41 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1
Nov 03 14:02:41 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1478196161.451:21): apparmor="DENIED" 
Nov 03 14:02:41 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1478196161.451:22): apparmor="DENIED"

Comment: So clearly it's an apparmor issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having wasn't a libaio library error but an apparmor error. The mysqld profile in Ubuntu's apparmor was too restrictive. I disabled apparmor's MySQLd profile using the tutorial here (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-howto-disable-apparmor-commands/) and was able to successfully install and use the mysql-server! Thanks for all the help guys, and sorry I wasn't more clear on the issue.